# How to keep animated div within container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 tile divs in another container div.

When a div is clicked the other 3 disappear.

I'm trying to get the div that was clicked on the fill the container div after it was clicked but its not working out.

How can i get the div to animate towards the empty space left by the divs I minimized?

this is my code only difference is the position of the div's since JsFiddle's result window is smaller than my browser:

```
<h1 id ='title'>Welcome to TalposMedia</h1>
<div class='navTilesContainer'>
    <div id="profile" class="navTile topLeft"><p>Profile</p></div>
    <div id="contact" class="navTile topRight"><p>Contact</p></div>
    <div id="showcase" class="navTile bottomLeft"><p>Showcase</p></div>
    <div id="resume" class="navTile bottomRight"><p>Resume</p></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w15ond4L/

Comment: the way your fiddle is working...it looks like your going to need to add some conditionals for each button pertaining to the expansion...it seems like they all expand to the correct size...but they arent being repositioned, you need to modify the x, y of the top left corner for each button except for profile (because that one starts in the top left it doesn't need to be repositioned)...at least thats what it seems like at first glance

Comment: Repositioning them would be inconsistent because the top left tile would never need to be repositioned and only the other three would be moving around Im trying to get the tiles to expand in the direction of the open space that the other tiles left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $target.animate({
        height  : '+=335px',
        width   : '100%',
        top     : 0,
        left    : 0
```

Comment: Can you add more details to why adding `top:0,left:0` solve the issue?

Comment: I'm pretty amazed that it was this simple! Though i'm not sure why it works but anyway thankyou

Comment: when you use 0 like that in css...it is being used absolutely...so it basically means, no matter what, put the `div` at the very top, and all the way to the left.

Comment: @Shubh This is because jQuery animation (and jQuery css manipulation) works in one of two ways: either an endpoint or a delta. The `height` part of the animation is a delta, saying "increase the height by 335px", due to the `+=` prefix. So if the height was 1px, animate to become 336px. But my code is providing a endpoint style. "Animate the top of the element to become 0 from its parent, and the left to become 0 from its parent". So now every clicked element's top-left corner will be animated to travel to 0 top and 0 left. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Marius'Romania'Talpos StackOverflow wouldn't let me @ tag 2 people, but I wanted to let you know I provided an explanation. Good luck!

Comment: @Nate Your answer was flagged as low quality answer([code only answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation)). It was missing explanation! I would suggest you to add the explanation by editing your answer.

Comment: @Shubh The "accepted" answer to your Meta link ends with "In short, leave a comment asking them to elaborate. If they refuse to do so, downvote and move on if you think the lack of explanation really detracts from the quality." My answer was brief because I assumed it was a simple oversight. When OP and another mentioned they didn't understand my answer, a third party AND I both provided detailed explanations.